# Método da API busca a informação mas não aparece no front-end

Tags: java, angularjs, jpa, spring, spring-mvc

Tenho um método da minha API que faz uma busca no banco de dados

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/entidadesUsuarioPermissao/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<PermissoesPaginas>> buscarEntidadesUsuarioP(@PathVariable Long id) {

        Collection<PermissoesPaginas> entidadesBuscados = ppService.buscarTodas(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(entidadesBuscados, HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

e vem todas as informações de que preciso quais sejam: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porém, quando eu faço o debug no front-end o objeto entidade não aparece

essa é a minha resposta que chega no front end 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

notem que o objeto entidade não aparece.

o método do front-end é este:

```
$http({
                method : 'GET',
                url : '/entidadesUsuarioPermissao/'+id

            }).then(function(response) {
                $scope.usuarios = response.data;


            }, function(response) {
                console.log(response.data);
                console.log(response.status);
            });
```

saída do console na tela

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não está dentro de usuarios > permissoesPaginasCollection ?

Answer (score 0):

Conforme verificado, o problema estava no método get dentro da classe PermissoesPaginas, onde o nome da entidade não estava mapeada para exibição.

Comment: Rhadamez, nenhuma das alternativas ajudou, continuou o mesmo resultado.

Comment: Ok, então troca o tipo de "Collection" por "List", e tenta a segunda opção da minha resposta.

Comment: Imprime no console essa lista pra ver se quando o método é chamado, ele está realmente imprimindo, outra coisa, você utiliza o postman pra testar a API?

Comment: Na verdade eu tenho testado na tela pois já está pronta.. o console está na pergunta..

Comment: Mas no console da sua IDE, ele chega a exibir os valores da lista?

Comment: sim.. aparecem todas as informações..

Comment: Nesse caso, o problema deve estar na chamada dessa endpoint, você consegue disponibilizar o código que está chamando pra mostrar no html?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67662/discussion-between-eduardo-krakhecke-and-rhadamez-gindri-hercilio).

Answer (score 0):

Adiciona "@ResponseBody" na sua anotação e utilize esse jackjson

```
@RequestMapping (value="/services/SayHello2Me" , method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
```

Comment: nada mudou, continua vindo a mesma coisa..